# Implementing a policy class using Pundit - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I writing a class called `AdminPolicy` This class is basically trying to say whether or not a user is an admin... Right now I pass in the `current_user` and the `current_account`. I basically have a join to table between user and account and that has the admin attribute on it. Everything seems to be working fine except for this error that I'm getting `undefined local variable or method 'admin_policy'`. Here is my code, I can't seem to figure out what is wrong?

### admin policy class

```
class AdminPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :account

  def initialize(user, account)
    @user = user
    @account = account
  end

  def allow_access?(user, account)
    membership = account.membership_for?(user)

    if membership.admin
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

### pages controller

```
def admin_policy
  @admin_policy ||= AdminPolicy.new(current_user, current_account)
end
```

### dashboard.html.erb

```
<% if admin_policy.allow_access?(current_user, current_account) %>
  <div class="admin-dashboard">
    <%= render partial: "admin_dashboard" %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="worker-dashboard">
    <%= render partial: "worker_dashboard" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### Error

[image]

So its saying that `admin_policy` is undefined.. Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `allow_access?` doesn't need to receive parameters, so your policy should be

```
class AdminPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :account

  def initialize(user, account)
    @user = user
    @account = account
  end

  def allow_access?
    membership = account.membership_for?(user)

    if membership.admin
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

In your views, you can call it in this way (this is not the only way to do it)

```
<% if policy(Admin).allow_access? %>
  <div class="admin-dashboard">
    <%= render partial: "admin_dashboard" %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="worker-dashboard">
    <%= render partial: "worker_dashboard" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Be sure to read carefully the [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#policies).

**Heads up!**

If you are inheriting from `ApplicationPolicy` you don't need to include `attr_reader` and `ìnitialize` method because both are defined by default in the `ÀpplicationPolicy`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% if @admin_policy.allow_access?(current_user, current_account) %>
```

Hope this will helping you.

Comment: if you are satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up